# how to extract particular field from JSON using NewtonSoft.Json in C#

Tags: json

I am using Newtonsoft.Json in my C# application and want to know how to extract accountId from following JSON content which stored in string.

Any help is really appreciated.

`{ "AccountListResponse": { "Accounts": { "Account": [ {"accountId":"0001","accountIdKey":"key1","accountMode":"ON"}, {"accountId":"00021","accountIdKey":"key21","accountMode":"ON"}, {"accountId":"00031","accountIdKey":"key31","accountMode":"ON"} ] } } }`

i tried reading api, but still couldn't find out how to use. becaise of array, it got more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

first here is your model

```
 public class Account
{
    public string accountId { get; set; }
    public string accountIdKey { get; set; }
    public string accountMode { get; set; }
}

public class AccountListResponse
{
    public Accounts Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class Accounts
{
    public List<Account> Account { get; set; }
}

public class AccountListResponseMain
{
    public AccountListResponse AccountListResponse { get; set; }
}
```

then now you loop through

```
 var regModel = new AccountListResponseMain();
                regModel.AccountListResponse =data.AccountListResponse;
                

                for (int a = 0; a < data.Accounts.Length; a++)
                {
                    var inv = new Account();

                    inv.accountId = a.accountId;
     
             
                }
```

N/B not perfect but you get the idea

Comment: thanks for your prompt response, but one this is not clear to me is how my string e.g. string s1 , which holds my .json content, how it get processed by newtonsoft.json class and which api i should use? thanks in advance.